# unique function of Matlab not working properly

Tags: arrays, matlab, unique

Consider the following code:

```
Nor_x_f=0.23;N=10;T_r=1.2;fun=@(x) tan(x*(1-Nor_x_f)/sqrt(T_r))+(sqrt(1/T_r)*tan(Nor_x_f*x));ub=6*pi;
while 1
    p_zeros= NaN*ones(100,1); %Possible zeroes
    t_u_zeros=NaN*ones(1,100);
    starting_points=linspace(0,ub,200);
    for i=1:200
        % Look for the zeros in the functions current window.
        p_zeros(i)=fzero(fun, starting_points(i));
    end
    u_zeros=p_zeros(diff(p_zeros)>1e-4);%Unique zeros
    k=1;
    for i =1:size(u_zeros,1) %This is a column vector
        if abs(fun(u_zeros(i))) < 0.01
            t_zeros(k)=u_zeros(i);
            t_u_zeros=unique(t_zeros);
            k=k+1;
        end
    end
    if size(t_u_zeros,2) == N+1
    break;
    elseif size(t_u_zeros,2) > N+1
    ub=ub-(pi/4);
    elseif size(t_u_zeros,2) < N+1
    ub=ub+(pi/4);
    end
end
```

This code gives the output of t_u_zeros as

> -3.98469691056082e-20 3.41630960177882    10.0537539879730    13.4659245023669    16.8860053973345    23.5241876330466    26.9318782023573    30.3553383996551    36.9949907705359    40.3978901377654    40.3978901377654

Note the last two elements are similar even after using unique function (`t_u_zeros=unique(t_zeros);`) and using this line: `u_zeros=p_zeros(diff(p_zeros)>1e-4);` to eliminate same digits.

What is going on? What am I missing? Or is this a bug in unique function?

Comment: Use the debugger, set the breakpoint, calculate the difference. You don't see all digits, I am sure there is a difference in one of the later digits.

Comment: @Daniel: Thanks for replying. You are right about the digits. But I have eliminated that possibility by using the line `u_zeros=p_zeros(diff(p_zeros)>1e-4);` before using unique function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to isolate the problem and reproduce the problem:

```
>>p_zeros=[1,2,3,4,4,1.5,3.00001,99];
>>u_zeros=p_zeros(diff(p_zeros)>1e-4);
>>u_zeros

u_zeros =

    1.0000    2.0000    3.0000    1.5000    3.0000
```

I am not sure how your filter should work (is it intended to exclude numbers like 4 and 99?) but it is definitely keeping variables with values close to each other. It might be that `sort(p_zero)` helps. If you have problems fixing the problem, please update your question and describe what these lines should do. Also note that `diff(x)` has n-1 element while `x` has n elements. That probably drops the last element.

Comment: `sort(p_zero)` worked like a charm. Thanks a million :)